# Blinking Cursor in the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how to make a cursor blink in the textarea even before you click on it?

Like https://medium.com/p/new-post

Comment: `elt.focus()` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `autofocus` to accomplish this, [check out w3schools for basic information on it](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp).

`<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>`

Comment: @torazaburo , what's the point in -1 if it's what the OP asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the styling is set to show no cursor.
And try below examples:

[**Cursor examples in CSS**](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you download a blinking gif then put it as backround of your text area to make it blink. Then when you type it will go away.

Add bootstrap form like this to clone the same display: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/146/)

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Tell your story.." rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
```

Bootstrap forms: bootstrapform